# How do I extract an 8 Digit Number from a json in python?

Tags: python, json

this is the whole json that I get as output from the function:

```
{'actingBackgroundAnimationState': 'is-acting-background', 'activeActionType': 'pick', 'areSummonerActionsComplete': False, 'assignedPosition': '', 'banIntentSquarePortratPath': '', 'cellId': 0, 'championIconStyle': 'display:none', 'championName': '', 'currentChampionVotePercentInteger': -1, 'entitledFeatureType': '', 'isActingNow': True, 'isDonePicking': False, 'isOnPlayersTeam': True, 'isPickIntenting': False, 'isPlaceholder': False, 'isSelf': 
True, 'pickSnipedClass': '', 'shouldShowActingBar': True, 'shouldShowBanIntentIcon': False, 'shouldShowExpanded': True, 'shouldShowRingAnimations': False, 'shouldShowSelectedSkin': False, 'shouldShowSpells': True, 'showMuted': False, 'showTrades': False, 'skinId': 0, 'skinSplashPath': '', 'slotId': 0, 'spell1IconPath': '/lol-game-data/assets/DATA/Spells/Icons2D/Summoner_flash.png', 'spell2IconPath': '/lol-game-data/assets/DATA/Spells/Icons2D/SummonerIgnite.png', 'statusMessageKey': 'picking_champion', 'summonerId': 2701174967428448, 'tradeId': -1}
```

I only need the number from this: 'summonerId': 2701174967428448

Answer (score 1):

If you have the result stored in a variable as a Python `dict`, you only have to specify the 'summonerId' key and you will get its assigned value:

```
json_result = {'actingBackgroundAnimationState': 'is-acting-background'...}
print(json_result['summonerId'])
```

However, if the JSON returned by your function is a string, you would first have to convert it to a Python `dict` by using the `json` package:

```
import json

json_result = "{'actingBackgroundAnimationState': 'is-acting-background'...}"
json_obj = json.loads(json_result)

print(json_obj['summonerId'])
```

Check the [official Python docs](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#dictionaries) for more info about dictionaries.

Comment: Thanks it worked, I dont know how it works, but it did! Probably has something to do the way dict works

Comment: You're welcome! If you have doubts about Python built-in types like dictionaries, the [Official Python docs](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#dictionaries) can help you a lot!

Answer (score 0):

Here is one way:

```
import json

data = """{
   "actingBackgroundAnimationState":"is-acting-background",
   "activeActionType":"pick",
   "areSummonerActionsComplete":false,
   "assignedPosition":"",
   "banIntentSquarePortratPath":"",
   "cellId":0,
   "championIconStyle":"display:none",
   "championName":"",
   "currentChampionVotePercentInteger":-1,
   "entitledFeatureType":"",
   "isActingNow":true,
   "isDonePicking":false,
   "isOnPlayersTeam":true,
   "isPickIntenting":false,
   "isPlaceholder":false,
   "isSelf":true,
   "pickSnipedClass":"",
   "shouldShowActingBar":true,
   "shouldShowBanIntentIcon":false,
   "shouldShowExpanded":true,
   "shouldShowRingAnimations":false,
   "shouldShowSelectedSkin":false,
   "shouldShowSpells":true,
   "showMuted":false,
   "showTrades":false,
   "skinId":0,
   "skinSplashPath":"",
   "slotId":0,
   "spell1IconPath":"/lol-game-data/assets/DATA/Spells/Icons2D/Summoner_flash.png",
   "spell2IconPath":"/lol-game-data/assets/DATA/Spells/Icons2D/SummonerIgnite.png",
   "statusMessageKey":"picking_champion",
   "summonerId":2701174967428448,
   "tradeId":-1
}"""

json_data = json.loads(data)

print(json_data["summonerId"])
```

Prints:

```
2701174967428448
```

Answer (score 0):

Load json first using `json` lib:

```
import json
data= json.loads('path/to/.json')
my_json = json.dumps(data, indent = 4)
print(my_json)
```

now you can nicely call to certain KEYs. Cos it has KEYS : VALUES structure. So just do:

```
print(my_json['summonerId'])
```